# JavaScript adding an element to a div based on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

For context, currently working on an electron app that will help me learn Japanese.

I am wanting to add courses to a `div` based on a list of JSON objects but what I have tried so far isn't working. How would I achieve my goal?

My Code:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./master.css">
        <title>Nippon Ren</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1 id="app-title">Nippon Ren</h1>

            <div class="section">
                <h2 class="section-title">Continue</h2>
                
                <div class="section-content" id="c" onload="loadCurrentCourses()">
                    <a href="./courses/add.html"><div id="courses-add">
                        
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="section">
                <h2 class="section-title">Revision</h2>

                <div class="section-content revision-current">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Page JS -->
        <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`renderer.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises')

const COURSES_CURRENT = document.getElementById("courses-current")


let coursesCurrent
const getCurrentCourses = async () => {
    try {
        await fs.access("./data/current_courses.json")
    } catch {
        coursesCurrent = { courses: [] }
    }

    if (!coursesCurrent) {
        coursesCurrent = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./data/current_courses.json", "utf8"))
    }
}

const loadCurrentCourses = async () => {
    getCurrentCourses()
    for (i in coursesCurrent["courses"]) {
        let nextCourse = document.createElement("div")
        nextCourse.className = "card"
        document.getElementById("c").innerHTML += nextCourse
    }
}
```

`data/current_courses.json`

```json
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Getting Started with Hirigana",
            "desc": "Intro"
        }
    ]
}
```

The other method for adding the courses is:

```js
...
const loadCurrentCourses = async () => {
    getCurrentCourses()
    for (i in coursesCurrent["courses"]) {
        let nextCourse = document.createElement("div")
        nextCourse.className = "card"
        document.getElementById("c").appendChild(nextCourse)
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running JavaScript directly in the browser, but using `require()` is only possible when running the code using NodeJS. If you want to use `require()`, but run the code in a browser, try using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Also, I don't see any element with id `courses-current` in your HTML.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow to see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function, something like this

```js
const course = {
    "courses": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Getting Started with Hirigana",
            "desc": "Intro"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Getting Started with Hirigana",
            "desc": "Intro"
        }
    ]
}
course.courses.map((currentElement) => {
    console.log(currentElement); //append child here using the currentElement value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `for` loop didn't work and that I was using the `createElement` and `appendChild` wrong.

I have still not yet figured out how to loop through the array but creating the elements work now